# Single Sign On with external system

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on

I have a SharePoint site and as well as an external payroll site. SharePoint uses AD authentication and the external payroll uses custom authentication (Database) with UserName and Password.

My requirement is to have a link inside a SharePoint Site for e.g My Payroll. On clicking this it should take to the Payroll Site without asking any further authentication.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Please tag by functionality and not by version or product. This helps to attract more attention to your question. If a tag you'd like to use is missing, simply flag a moderator.

Answer (score 5):

You need to implement single sign on (SSO).  Robert Bogue has a good step by step.

http://www.thorprojects.com/blog/archive/2008/08/02/moss-single-sign-on-setup-step-by-step.aspx

Comment: Ok If we use the above technique you can Map the AD User with the appropriate credentials in the SSO Database . And you can retrieve the Credential using the APPlication ID . Now i have a link in the sharepoint site Payroll.Now this should take directly to the Payroll Site. So is there any adjustment should be done on the Payroll site . Is there any similar implementation document ?

Comment: No changes should have to be made on the receiving system, but you will have to create / extend the SSO service to work with your particular app.  Your payroll provider may have instructions on doing this already, but you'll have to contact them for that information.  Additionally you can look at other Microsoft SSO technologies like Active Directory Federation Services (AD FS), and the Forefront products; Threat Management Gateway (TMG); and Unified Access Gateway (UAG).

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand your problem you can only do mapping based on yours AD accounts. External system shoud have mapping "table" which can be called from login page. For given AD user (read current user and take any unique attribute) appropriate username/password should be passed to custom authentication.